# Rails 4.1.0.beta1 upgrade gives me undefined local variable or method `generated_feature_methods'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

That is from lane with accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Rails 4.0.2 is fine, there are some changes with nested attributes?

Answer (score 4):

This issue can be caused by an outdated version of the protected_attributes gem. If you are using protected_attributes, upgrading to >= 1.0.6 should fix the issue.

See: https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes/issues/29